# VBA Excel using variables as cell reference

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA Code:

```
Public maxnumrows As Integer

Sub count_num_rows()
    maxnumrows = Sheets("Monetary All").UsedRange.Rows.Count
End Sub

Sub calc_external_sales()
    Sheets("Monetary All").[C5].FormulaLocal = "=SUMMEWENNS(Rawdata!K2:K3446;Rawdata!I2:I3446;""bezahlt"")"
End Sub
```

I would like the cell references in the calc_external_sales() to use the public variable in the range.

Example:
Rawdata!K2:K"maxnumrows"

How do I have to change the syntax?

Comment: btw you should also declare the variable as Long as there are far more rows in a sheet than an integer can hold

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can use a variable within a string

```
Sheets("Monetary All").[C5].FormulaLocal = _ 
"=SUMMEWENNS(Rawdata!K2:K" & maxnumrows & ";" & _ 
            "Rawdata!I2:I" & maxnumrows & ";""bezahlt"")"
```